# How to write Google Sing-in addOnCompleteListner in pyjnius&kivy?

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, pyjnius

I am adding Google Signin in ***kivy*** app. I am using ***pyjnius***, But i am stuck here

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
    // after this line 
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        .
        .
        .
    }

}
```

How do i write this **addOnCompleteListner** on python side using ***pyjnius***?